# Circular Dependency in Angular Components

Tags: angular, typescript, oop, circular-dependency

I have two components, AComponent and BComponent and a service that work with these two-component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-a',
    templateUrl: './a.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./a.component.scss']
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private tabService: TabService
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
    openB()
    {
    tabService.openTab(BComponent);
    }
```

}

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-b',
    templateUrl: './b.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./b.component.scss']
})
export class BComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private tabService: TabService
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
    openA()
    {
    tabService.openTab(AComponent);
    }
```

}

The problem is below warning Circular dependency between these two components.
how can I avoid circular dependency in this case?

imagine there are PersonListComponent And NewPersonComponent. And inside PersonListComponent there is a button opens NewPersonComponent in a tab,and In the newPersonComponent, there is a button opens PersonListComponent in a new tab.

Comment: What do the `openTab()` function ? Why are you passing the whole component ?

Comment: The openTab() is a general function that gets a Component and opens it into the dom like google chrome tabs...

Comment: Why are you passing Component B via Component A to the service? and Component A via Component B? What is your hierarchy in your app? Make your Parent Component pass either Component A or B? You haven't really provided enough information, can't magically come up with a solution.

Comment: I don't think you can open a new Tab with one component, or insert a component to the DOM like you do. Angular will reload AppComponent, then according to your routing system, it will decide which component to load. Could you provide your routing ?

Comment: imagine there are PersonListComponent And NewPersonComponent. And inside PersonListComponent there is a button opens NewPersonComponent in a tab,and In the newPersonComponent, there is a button opens PersonListComponent in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Given the example, both of the components should have a common parent.

Send an event upward from one of the child components to the parent. Then from the parent component, call the function to open one of the child components in a new tab.

Component A:

```js
export class AComponent implements OnInit {
    Output() OpenB: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

Component B:

```js
export class BComponent implements OnInit {
    Output() OpenA: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

Parent HTML:

```html
<app-bcomponent (openA)="openComponent('A')"></app-bcomponent>
<app-acomponent (openB)="openComponent('B')"></app-acomponent>
```

Parent ts:

```js
openComponent(component) {
    if (component === 'A') {
        tabService.openTab(AComponent);
    } else if (component === 'B') {
        tabService.openTab(BComponent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

According to what you said in comment, you have two solutions :

**1. Use a dialog box [(Angular Material)](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) for example**

The `createUser()` method will open a dialog box showing a form to create a new user.

I can't provide code here, it will be too long to show how Material Modal works.

---

**2. Make a route for PersonList, and another for NewPerson**

In your routing file, make something like :

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'persons', component: PersonListComponent },
  { path: 'create', component: NewPersonComponent },
]
```

Then in your html file you will be able to make :

```html
<a routerLink="/create" routerLinkActive="active"> Add </a>
```